# How can I rebind C-n from evil-paste-pop

Tags: key-bindings, init-file

I am trying to bind `C-n` and `C-p` to call `next-buffer` and `previous-buffer`. They seem to conflict with some `evil-mode` key bindings and I don't seem to be able to overwrite them. When I press them I get

```
Previous command was not evil-paste: evil-paste-pop
```

and

```
Previous command was not evil-paste: evil-paste-pop-next
```

for `C-n` and `C-p` respectively

In my `.emacs` file I have the following:

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-n"))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-n") 'next-buffer)
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-p"))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-p") 'previous-buffer)
```

The calls to `global-unset-key` were added as an attempt to resolve this issue, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unbinding a key requires the correct keymap to work.  You can look up Evil's keybindings in `evil-maps.el` with `M-x find-library`.  The following snippet unbinds both keys:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-n") nil)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-p") nil))
```

You can then bind both keys globally to something else and they will no longer be intercepted by Evil.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work in all `evil-mode` states:

```el
(evil-define-key
  '(normal insert visual replace operator motion emacs)
  'global
  (kbd "C-n") 'next-buffer)

(evil-define-key
  '(normal insert visual replace operator motion emacs)
  'global
  (kbd "C-p") 'previous-buffer)
```